# Is the process of shifting the front chainring on a road bike with 2 chainrings always a two-step (two click) process on the shifter?

Tags: shifter, chainring

I have a Shimano Claris groupset.
I was speaking to my bike mechanic and he was saying to shift the front derailer it is a 2 step process to change the front derailer.

As per the [manual](https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/um/6VX0A/UM-6VX0A-003-ENG.pdf) it says with regards to left hand lever operation:

> Push the lever in until it clicks then release it.
> If gear shifting did not complete, push the lever in until it clicks one
> more time

It also mentions about **Trimming operation (noise prevention mechanism)** - subtle touches to the left shifter to stop noises.

So is the process of shifting the front chainring on a road bike with 2 chainrings always a two-step (two click) process?

Comment: I’m not sure about Claris but on the 105 and Ultegra you can push the lever all the way. In fact it can be tricky to actually hit the trim position without shifting all the way.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on how old the groupset is.  Early front shifters had no fixed positions, so you could slide the lever to whereever produced no clatter.

When indexing came along, it was initially for the rear only.  Front indexed shifting was a more recent feature.

So a double chainring would have had exactly two positions, and a triple had three.  And the chain could just rub in certain combinations.

Then TRIM came along - it was a rest stop that was well under half-a-position across.  A double chainring might have had one extra position that is "slightly left of the big ring" so when you're in a big-big gear combination, the cage does not drag across the chain.
Likewise, the smaller chainring might have a "just right of normal" so a small-small combo avoids rub.
An indexed front shifter for a double chainring might therefore have 2, 3, or 4 positions and they're not equally spaced.

A front mech for a triple could plausibly have 3 main positions, an additional 2 on either side of the middle ring, and one more beside each other chainring for a total of 7, though I don't know if that was ever reached.

---

TRIM is controlled by doing "little shifts" on a compatible left-hand brifter - most can swing all the way to change one whole chainring, or about a third of that swing to move to a trim detent if one is there.  If one is not there, you won't feel it and releasing the brifter means nothing happens, so you'd need to do a full swing to get over a chainring.

Same goes when using the smaller "release" lever - a little push finds a trim position the other direction.

Its hard to explain further, but vary how much you push the lever and see what the front mech does.  Put the bike in a stand, unship the chain from the chainring, and actuate the left brifter while watching the derailleur may help.

Comment: When shifting from the small chainring to big chainring (not trimming) - is it recommended to always stop pushing the lever when a click is felt, return it to the original position and try again. Or can it just be done in one single swoop.

Comment: @tread for Shimano 6800 and 8000, if you’re in the big ring and you give the shift paddle a push, you can actually feel it click twice. From the small ring, if you just give the brake lever a swing, you may actually feel the two clicks in there as well. If you slowly push the brake lever until the first click, that’s not a full shift, you’re in the trim position.